# Display table in javascript without altering html

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i am not sure how to display my javascript program output in a table by not altering the html code, right now the output looked![enter image description here][1] left-aligned, i want to make the name goes underneath CUSTOMER NAME, and child goes underneath CHILD/ADULT, but right now when i added   in the javascript program it does not work. thanks for your help

```js
const MAX_CUSTOMERS = 5; //maximum customer on the trampoline is 5
var customerList = new Array(); //create new Array


function addAndDisplayCustomer() //function for add and display customer
  {
    

    var newCustomer = {}; //create new object  
    
    newCustomer.name = document.getElementById('name').value.trim(); //get name value
    newCustomer.childOrAdult = childOrAdult.options[childOrAdult.selectedIndex].value;  //get option value for child or adult
         
    displayCustomers(); //display customers
  }

function displayCustomers() //function for display customers
  {
    if (message = '')
      message = '[There are currently no customers on the trampoline]'; // no customer on the trampoline 
    else
    {
      var message = '<p><b>&nbsp;CUSTOMER NAME&nbsp;</b>\t\t<b>&nbsp;CHILD/ADULT&nbsp;</b></p>'; 

    for (var i = 0; i < customerList.length; i++)
      {
        message += '&nbsp; '+ String(customerList[i].name) + '; //name message
        message += ' + String(customerList[i].childOrAdult) + '&nbsp; //status message 
        message += '<button onclick="removeCustomer(' + i + ')">Remove this customer</button></td></tr>'; //add delete button 
      }
      
      }

     document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = message; //display message 
  }
```

Comment: Please define "it does not work".

Comment: just edited the code

Comment: Please edit the text, what happens instead of that you've expected?

Comment: when you add a customer, e.g Tom Child, the string does not appear underneath the title on the top CUSTOMER NAME, CHILD/ADULT, i want to display them in a table, so that the result looks tidier. right now Tom Child and the delete button appears cluster together on the left, i want to have three column.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using `<table><tbody>...</tbody></table>` tags to wrap your table. Just putting in table rows and columns by themselves won't work. Also you'll need to change the margins of the table so that it is centered (`0 auto` sets the left and right margins to auto which centers it).

That would change your JavaScript to be something like:

```
function displayCustomers() //function for display customers
  {
    if (message == '')
      message = '[There are currently no customers on the trampoline]'; // no customer on the trampoline 
    else
    {
      var message = '<table style="margin: 0 auto"><thead><tr><td><b>CUSTOMER NAME</b></td>';
      message += '<td><b>CHILD/ADULT</b></td><td></td></tr></thead><tbody>'; 

    for (var i = 0; i < customerList.length; i++)
      {
        message += '<tr><td>'+ String(customerList[i].name) + '</td>'; //name message
        message += '<td>' + String(customerList[i].childOrAdult) + '<td>'; //status message 
        message += '<td><button onclick="removeCustomer(' + i + ')">Remove this customer</button></td></tr>'; //add delete button 
      }

      message+= '</tbody></table>';

      }

        document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = message; //display message 
  }
```

Comment: u mean in html or javascript? i can't altered the html code. only javascript

Comment: Well, you are changing the innerHTML using JavaScript. I've added the edited displayCustomers() function.

Comment: Move the closing '</tbody></table>' tags out of the for loop.

Comment: i tired this and only the first row is correct for some reason ?

Comment: and the title row went all the way to the left

Comment: that's because of margins. Set the margin of the table to `0 auto` and it will center

Comment: i don't have a css, can i change the margin directly in the javascript code above ?

Comment: I added a style attribute to the table element

Answer (score 1):

you're not constructing your table properly; there's no `<table>` element, and your table header is just tabbed/whitepsace positioned. Put those in a table header. Also, you should be checking the customer list size instead of the previous contents of your message string.

```
function displayCustomers() { //function for display customers 
    // check customer list size, not the current message text
    if (customerList.length > 0) {
      message = '[There are currently no customers on the trampoline]'; // no customer on the trampoline 
    }
    else {
        var message = '<table><thead><tr><th>CUSTOMER NAME</th><th>CHILD/ADULT</th></tr></thead>'; 
        message += '<tbody>';

        for (var i = 0; i < customerList.length; i++) {
            message += '<tr><td>'+ String(customerList[i].name) + '</td>'; //name message
            message += '<td>' + String(customerList[i].childOrAdult) + '<td>'; //status message 
            message += '<td><button onclick="removeCustomer(' + i + ')">Remove this customer</button></td></tr>'; //add delete button 
        }
        message += '</tbody></table>';
    }

    document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = message; //display message 
  }
```

Comment: the title now go all the way to the left now

Comment: u mean use centre-align in javascript?

Comment: no, add `style="text-align: center;"` to the `th` tags, or put the styles into your stylesheet for the page